# ExpressJS memory leak caused by using closure?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, closures

I just learned about closure in JS and excited to try it in my project.
I have written the following code for acting as time checking whether cache is expired or not.

```
module.exports = {
needUpdateCache: function () {
    let start = -1;
    const timeoutMs = rDefines["10_MINUTES_MS"];
    return function () {
        if (start === -1) {
            start = Date.now();
            return true;
        }
        let diff = Date.now() - start;
        if (diff < timeoutMs) {
            return false
        } else {
            start = Date.now();
            return true;
        }
    }
}(),
```

Then in the main route controller, I have it called like this

```
exports.getData = function (req, res, next) {

if (!common.needUpdateCache()) {
    console.log('Still in caching period. Retrieve from saved local file');
    common.csvFile2jsonArray("data.txt").then((jsonObj) => {
        res.json({"songs": jsonObj});
    });
    return;
}
else // get new data from db and save it to local file data.txt
```

The reason why I'm thinking closure in my code is culprit is because the heapdump comparison shows lots of closure created by not collected which lead to pm2 show incremental memory usage. Here is the snapshot of heapdump

[image]

I have done research on closure and memory leak but got no clues why my code creates leak. I have fixed it by removing the usage of closure. However, I'm really curious about why I get memory leak with my code. If you have any clue, please help point it out so I can watch it out in the future. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You will need to inspect which closure exactly is the culprit, and over what data it closes. In the code you posted, there's no obvious mistake.

Comment: I'm only aware of that place using closure. Expanding the heapdump, going in detail each node of closure i cannot see the creation place of those closure (or maybe i don't have enough experience inspecting the heapdump file) Does it help if I include the heapdump files?

Comment: Pretty much every function is a closure, as closure creation is implicit in JS. E.g. the `(jsonObj) => {
        res.json({"songs": jsonObj});
    }` callback is a closure as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally eliminated the problem of leaking memory in my application by removing the mentioned closure parts. After which memory leak seems to be resolved.
But then I also have to remove the middleware express-formidable which sometimes causing the app hangs. 
Now my app is running without leaks
Thanks Bergi for you comment, appreciated.